# query = query % db.literal(args) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, string, format, mysql-python

I have a problem with MySQLdb that none of the previous questions have been able to help me with. I have a list called alltitles in python, I want to insert it into a table in MySQL. I have the following code in python:

```
for s in range(0,len(alltitles)):
    print alltitles[s]
    query = "INSERT INTO table (colname) VALUES ("+alltitles[s]+")"
    x=conn.cursor()
    x.execute(query, alltitles[s])
    row = x.fetchall()
```

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#180>", line 5, in <module>
    x.execute(query, alltitles[s])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: I have updated my code to this:
`conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="bi231293", db="mydb")
x = conn.cursor()
format = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(alltitles[1:101]))
query = "INSERT INTO table (colname) VALUES (%s)"  % format
x.execute(query, alltitles[1:101])`

ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (colname) VALUES ('Electrical technician', 'Consultant from HCL technologi' at line 1")

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the values both as literals in the string, and as the parameters to the query. You should only do it in one place, and that should be as the parameter.

(Also note in Python you should never iterate through a range with an index; iterate through the thing itself.)

```
x = conn.cursor()
for title in alltitles:
    print title
    query = "INSERT INTO table (colname) VALUES (%s)"
    x.execute(query, title)
    row = x.fetchall()
```

Comment: I hear you daniel, this is my revised code:
`x = conn.cursor()
for title in alltitles:
    print title
    query = "INSERT INTO table (colname) VALUES (%s)" % title
    x.execute(query, title)
    row = x.fetchall()`

However I still get the same error

Comment: But why did you do string substitution there? My code doesn't contain that. Use the code I posted.

Comment: You're right, I've  copied your code exact but now it returns a different error:
`ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (colname) VALUES ('')' at line 1")`

Comment: Do you have any empty strings in `alltitles?`

Answer (score 0):

Also, try to use:

```
for title_index,title in enumerate(alltitles):
    print title_index, title
    ...
```

(alltitles[title_index] will also give you title)